# How to pull typings in Deno

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, deno

I am checking out Deno and have found one of the starter examples very elegant:

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/x/std@v0.2.10/http/server.ts";
const s = serve("0.0.0.0:8000");

void async function main() {
  for await (const req of s) {
     req.respond({ body: new TextEncoder().encode("Hello World\n") });
  }
}()
```

I am using VS Code to author Deno scripts, but I am not sure how I can make the editor aware of typings for the imported functions, such as `serve`. I think it may be too soon for IDE support with Deno, but in case there is a solution or a workaround, I'd like to know about it.

Do I need to install a `@types` package or something like that? `import` or `reference` some `.d.ts` declaration files? How do I make VS Code offer code completion suggestions and display type annotations when using the `serve` function in this example and any imported scripts in Deno in general?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## tldr

Install [`denoland.vscode-deno`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=denoland.vscode-deno) extension <sup>1</sup>. Then [enable](https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno#usage) Deno in a particular project, like

`<proj-root>/.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
  "deno.enable": true, // enables extension
  "deno.lint": true, // inline deno lint diagnostics, requires `deno.unstable`
  "deno.unstable": true // also provides unstable type declarations in VS Code
}
```

Starting with [v2.3.0](https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno/releases/tag/v2.3.0), you can also use the [`deno: Init`](https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno/pull/207) wizard <sup>2</sup>:
[image]

To integrate a TS workspace version instead of VS Code built-in one, take a look at [linked docs](https://github.com/justjavac/typescript-deno-plugin#configuration).

<sup>1</sup> <sub>[This one](https://github.com/justjavac/vscode-deno) is deprecated.</sub>
<sup>2</sup> <sub>Note: In a new empty project, at least one source file needs to exist before the wizard works properly.</sub>

---

## More details

### What does the extension do?

- permits explicit `.ts` extensions in VS Code
- resolves URL import specifiers like `"https://deno.land/std@0.56.0/http/server.ts"`
- integrates Deno runtime types (e.g. `Deno.writeFile`)

### How to resolve types for `.ts` modules

With above extension, VS Code permits `.ts` file extensions for imports and resolves URL imports to a [local disk cache](https://deno.land/manual/linking_to_external_code#linking-to-third-party-code). The compiler can use these cached type definitions to do checks. Last, fetch all sources and restart TS server / reload VS Code:

```sh
deno cache https://deno.land/std/http/server.ts # fetch and compile from URL 
# or main project file
deno cache <your main file>.ts # fetches all its dependencies
```

`server.ts` is part of the [Standard Library](https://deno.land/std), which is just a more strictly maintained collection of remote `.ts` modules, so it also will be typed correctly.

### How to resolve types for `.js` modules

Deno provides [additional ways](https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/typescript#using-typescript) to reference `.d.ts` files for `.js` files.

Specify type definition at import code location:

```
// @deno-types="./foo.d.ts"
import * as foo from "./foo.js";
```

Specify type definition at host code location:

```
/// <reference types="./foo.d.ts" />
export const foo = "foo";
```

Alternative: Deno can read a custom [`X-TypeScript-Types`](https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/typescript#x-typescript-types-custom-header) HTTP header from remote imports.

### How to use a custom `tsconfig.json`

A given `tsconfig.json` file in a project is merged with the Deno default config, e.g.:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // set a custom, deviant value
    "noImplicitAny": false // deno default is true
    // (this is just an example - use strong types, whenever possible)
  }
}
```

Include [`-c`](https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/typescript#custom-typescript-compiler-options) option, so VS Code and Deno CLI have the same compiler settings:

```
deno run -c ./tsconfig.json main.ts
```

### How to use [`--unstable`](https://deno.land/manual/runtime/stability) types

The easiest option is to set [`"deno.unstable": true`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=denoland.vscode-deno#user-content-configuration) ([PR](https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno/pull/125)) in `settings.json` and restart VS Code, see the `tldr` section.

#### Manual alternative

```sh
cd <your-project>
deno types --unstable > deno.runtime.d.ts
touch tsconfig.json # (1); jsconfig.json for JS projects also possible
```

VS Code [automatically includes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#common-questions) `deno.runtime.d.ts` with an existent `tsconfig.json` (1).

---

## Breaking Changes

### `vscode-deno` v1.26.0

The extension needs to be [explicitly enabled](https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno/pull/122) by `"deno.enable": true` in `.vscode/settings.json` of the project (default is `false`). Before, the default had been `true`.

### `vscode-deno` < 1.25.0

Install Deno types in every case (stable and unstable) - see `"How to use --unstable types"`.

Comment: For the unstable api, after performing the above, execute the command `deno types --unstable > lib/deno_runtime.unstable.d.ts`

Answer (score 5):

Update: [vscode-deno](https://github.com/justjavac/vscode-deno) works fairly well.

Below is the current solution:

1. Add https://github.com/kitsonk/deno_ls_plugin to your workspace. Edit your `tsconfig.json` and replace paths to `http` and `https` imports with the local cache location of the remote dependencies (usually under `$HOME/.deno/deps/http` and `$HOME/.deno/deps/https`)
2. Create a `typings/` folder. Run `deno --types > typings/deno.d.ts`. Deno would output a type definition file for the core API.
3. Now the problem becomes that VS Code has no idea about fetching remote dependencies when you import. To address this, once you added a new remote `import`, run `deno --prefetch your_file.ts` to pull down all the dependencies. To make things simpler, I would suggest keep all your remote dependencies in a single file `deps.ts` (and run `--prefetch` on this file) and re-export stuff so that other files in your project could make use of the deps.

Comment: Your point 2 was something I was looking for my purpose. Trying to do `Deno in Emacs` along-side `tide`. Now I got hold of Deno typings to be fed into `tide`. Thank You !!!

Answer (score 1):

Download [lib.deno.d.ts](https://github.com/denoland/deno/releases/download/v1.34.1/lib.deno.d.ts) from this url `https://github.com/denoland/deno/releases/download/v1.34.1/lib.deno.d.ts`

Then in jsconfig.json, add downloaded d.ts file location in `types` array

```json
"types": ["./lib.deno.d.ts"]
```